# What is this function composed of?

Tags: real-analysis

What is this function composed of?

$f(x)=\log{\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{5-x^2}}}$

This is a composed function and I have to calculate the derivative but I don't know what it is composed of. Hint please?

Comment: You can take it step by step.  It may require repeated applications of the chain rule and/or quotient rule, but you should have all the tools you need.  As for "what is it composed of"... I see a logarithm, I see a division, I see an addition... a square root... a square... and a subtraction.  If you really wanted to, you could treat this as nine or ten compositions in sequence (*though you may find it shorter and easier to do multiple steps simultaneously*)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with $h(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{5-x^2}}$ and $g(x)=\log x$? Then 
$$
f(x)=g(h(x))
$$

Comment: What about that root and the $x^2$? Aren't they also parts of the composed function?

Comment: @user554506 sure you can go deeper down the rabbit hole if you would like, but if your goal is to find the derivative, then i think you can just tackle $h$ with the quotient rule pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$f(x)=ßlog(x)-\log(1+\sqrt{5-x^2})$$ and we get by the chain rule
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{5-x^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2}(5-x^2)^{-1/2}(-2x)$$
You can simplify this derivative!